# My account is deleted

Tags: whatsapp

My WHATSAPP account was off for 55 days as my phone was stolen. I bought a new iPhone X and replaced my number only to realize that my account was deleted. I am a sole admin of existing WhatsApp group. How do I rejoin the group.

I will be grateful for any help rendered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a mobile application

Answer (score 1):

Your account was probably not deleted.

However, you must use the same number to access the account. There's a [procedure](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/27585377/?category=5245246) to keep the account with a new number but it must be done from the already existing number.

If you have a new number and never transfered the account for the new number then, obviously, your previous account won't show up and you won't be able to recover it.